# Hadoop MR job is always in pending status

Tags: hadoop

I simply run a word count MapReduce job, share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar, on Hadoop 2.6.0, I found that the job is ACCEPTED but always in pending.

I start Hadoop with very basic pseudo-distributed configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- mapred-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- yarn-site.xml -->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I check my logs and I see some ERRORS.

In resourcemanager logs:

```
2015-05-21 15:02:10,823 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmnode.RMNodeImpl: Node 192.168.11.2:54225 reported UNHEALTHY with details: 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /tmp/hadoop-stephen/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /Users/stephen/devel/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs
```

In nodemanager logs:

```
2015-05-21 15:02:09,716 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService: Most of the disks failed. 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /tmp/hadoop-stephen/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /Users/stephen/devel/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs
```

I even see that I have 1 unhealthy node in Resource Manager page (where the port is 8088). I see the same errors even I remove the file system and `hdfs namenode -format` again and again.

Right now I only can guess my broken/unhealthy node make my MR job always in pending, if I am right, how to fix it?

(I can make Hadoop 2.5.2 run successfully with same configurations.)
(Env: Mac Yosemite, Oracle JDK 1.7.0_79)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your logs,without which it is very difficult to help you

Comment: I revised my quesiton